# How to unset variable in C#?

Tags: c#

How can I unset variable? For example, PHP has an `unset($var)` function.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is not really an equivalent to "unset".

The closest match I know is the use of the [default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d(VS.80).aspx) keyword.

For example:

```
MyType myvar = default(MyType);
string a = default(string);
```

The variable will still be "set", but it will have its default value.

Comment: `int[] array1 = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10 };` and then `int array1 = default(int);` returns 
>> A local variable named 'array1' is already defined in this scope

Comment: Addressing the above comment: 
That is because you are redeclaring the local variable `array1` (you initially declare it as `int[] array1`, then attempt to declare it a second time as `int array1`).  Assuming you weren't intending to change the type from `int[]` to `int` (which is not possible in C#), your fix should be: `array1 = default(int[]);`

Answer (score 28):

You can't. There's no notion of "unsetting" a variable. You can set it to a different value - 0, null, whatever's appropriate. Instance/static variables don't even have a concept of whether the variable is set/unset, and local variables only have "definitely assigned" or "not definitely assigned".

What is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: The most important use for unset() in PHP is to unset variables which are not defined in a scope (function or class), IMO. Because of that, C# does not need unset in the same way that PHP does. :)

Answer (score 12):

Generally setting it to null does the job (for variable of types like int you would have to make it a nullable version int?).

If you only want to use the variable for a short period of time in a bigger function you can scope it, like this:

```
{
    int i = 2;
}
```

The variable will only last until the closing brace.

If these do not cover your circumstance then can you elaborate on where you need to do this.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you'd like to free the *object* that the variable is referencing:

```
MyVar = null;
```

Comment: NB this is not guaranteed to dispose the object to which `MyVar` was pointing.

Answer (score 3):

Value-type variables don't need unset. They are permanently allocated.

For reference-type variables you just set them to *null* and the garbage collector will destroy the associated object (and free the memory). But note that the variable itself will continue to exist throughout its scope (code block, method, object life, ...)

If you want to use this to free memory then just set all not-needed objects to null and wait for the garbage collector to do its job.

**Edit**: As noted in comments I ommited to say that the garbage collector won't start the collection immediately. This will happen usually when the framework tries to allocated memory and can't find enough free. It's possible to start "manually" a garbage collection, but it's not advisable and might worsen the behavior of the program. For most purposes the default behavior of the GC should be enough.

Comment: The object will be destroyed as soon as there is *no* variable providing a reference to it any more.

Comment: @hangy: It's not as simple as that. The object's memory will only be freed the next time the GC runs (for that generation), not as soon as there's no variable referring to it. There are other complications such as circular references (not a problem) and finalization. 300 chars isn't enough!

Comment: 300 chars aint enough, right. :) I just added this because, just using rslite's answer, one might think the object is gone as soon as one variable is set to null. You're correct, of course, it is not always as simple as that.

Comment: The GC walks the reference tree back from the leaf (in this case, an object possibly about to be collected) to the root.  If it isn't rooted, it gets collected.  Other, also unrooted, objects may hold a reference and it will still be collected.

Comment: @Will: No, it doesn't walk from leaf to root. It uses mark/sweep, walking from all known roots and then collecting everything which isn't marked. You can't navigate leaf->root - an object doesn't know what refers to it.

Comment: To be clear, you don't need to set the variables to null for them to be collected as suggested in the parent comment. When a collection occurs it will (barring edge cases) collect things that are no longer referenced, whether they are null or not. http://ablog.apress.com/?p=1097

Answer (score 2):

To unset environment variable use the same Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable method, but pass null, or string.Empty as a value http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96xafkes(v=vs.110).aspx

> "If value is empty and the environment variable named by variable exists, the environment variable is deleted."

Comment: I don't believe that the OP is referring to environment variables. OTOH I don't know PHP, so maybe this sort of variable _are_ environment variables?

Answer (score 1):

For an object you can set it to null, a string is best set to String.Empty, or you can declare a variable as nullable such as:

```
int? i = null;
```

Comment: What makes you say that a string is best set to string.Empty? It entirely depends on what you want to achieve. I rarely need to do anything like this anyway, but when I do I usually use null for strings. Why pretend you've got a reference to a meaningful object?

Answer (score 1):

You could define a scope for that variable. When the scope exits, the variable will no longer be defined:

```
System.Console.WriteLine("let's give this a try: ");
{
    int j = 0;
    System.Console.WriteLine(j);
}
//Won't compile with the following line.
//System.Console.WriteLine(j);
```

Comment: +1, This should be the accepted answer, it is the closest thing to the behaviour in C family of languages there is.

Answer (score -1):

personally I just go

**variable = Nothing**

that seems to free up the resources especially when working with mobile phones!

Comment: sure, just don't expect to get a true value from IsNothing(variable)!

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to make it `null`, and to do so:

```
int? Foo = 5;
Foo = null;
```

Comment: Why `null`? And if a variable not _nullable_?

Comment: Consider to clarify/explain your answer, explain the flow etc

Comment: @Jackaw, if you want to check if the variable is not null, you can do something like this
`if (Foo! != null) {}`. I made it nullable so you can kind of free it up from the memory by assigning `null` to it.